# can't change textfield in scrollview

Tags: iphone

Can’t change text field in scrollView.

ScrollView is fine:

```
[self.view addSubview:myScrollViewObj];
```

Assorted column / row fields, those work too:

```
(nonatomic,retain)
(init, alloc)
row02_col03.text = @”456”;
[myScrollViewObj addSubview:row02_col03];
```

(Too much like work to use a table view.)  I can change the contents of row02_col03

```
row02_col03.text = @”789”;
```

but “789” over-writes “456.”  Both values are on the screen at the same time and in the same position.  Happens w/textView, happens with Label.

Huh?  OK, if updating didn’t work, then remove the “old” field before writing to a new one.

```
[row02_col03 removeFromSuperview];
(init, alloc again)
row02_col03.text = @”789”;
```

Now “456” doesn’t go anywhere (so much for “remove”), yet the NSLog statements shows that the new field correctly contains “789.”

Weird.  Another stackoverflow entry suggested using tags.  Did that:

```
(init, alloc again)
row02_col03.tag = 10;
row02_col03.text = @”456”;
[[myScrollViewObj viewWithTag:10] removeFromSuperview];
(init, alloc again)
row02_col03.tag = 10;
row02_col03.text = @”789”;
```

Yes, I put NSLog statements before and after; the removeFromSuperview line did execute.  No, presence / absence of “retain” made no difference

It’s an old app, and I didn’t have to update anything, but now that I need to (and can’t) I’d like to understand what I’m missing.  Anyone have a clue?

Comment: post more codes... This looks like a small (either forget to removefromsuperview or forget to addsubview) problem - so need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try `row02_col03.text = nil;`
Before adding new value,to remove old one.